# Searching for specific string in a field in awk

Tags: bash, text, awk, text-processing

I'm using Cygwin for Windows to code in Awk. I'm actually very new to this language. I've written a small one liner to print the whole line if there is a specific string in a particular field.

```
 $  awk -F '[:,]' '{if($9 == "QueCmd0") print $0 }'  #QueCmd0 is the name of the string.
```

The ":" and "," are field separators.

And the code works fine for small text files (up to 6-7MB or so) but this code shows no output when the .txt file is large (around 10-15MB). I don't know where the problem lies.

Is there anything else which I ought to know?

**Update: The issue was with text encoding, change the encoding from unicode to UTF-8**

Comment: On a sidenote, your script if equivalent to `'$9 == "QueCmd0"'`. This is how blocks work in `awk`.

Comment: Can you update the question with a sample line from the entire log?

Comment: `awk` works just as well with large files just as well as it works with small files.  As Inian says, you need to show one or more lines from the large file that you think should have printed but didn't.  After you select those lines, you can click on [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37742363/edit) and add them to the question.

Comment: Maybe the large file doesn't have any lines that match.

Comment: sorry people thanks for showing interest, the problem was with text encoding, the code works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[:,]' '{if($9 == "QueCmd0") print $0}' 
awk -F '[:,]' '{if($9 == "QueCmd0") print}' 
awk -F '[:,]' '$9 == "QueCmd0" {print}'
awk -F '[:,]' '$9 == "QueCmd0"'
```

There is nothing inherent in a larger files that causes awk to fail,
the os you are using, that I can not vouch for.

maybe it would like a shorter version?

Comment: yes, the problem occurred because the text was encoded in unicode, whiuch when changed to UTF-8, worked